# How can I create and implement my own font?

Tags: fonts

I want to essentially import a custom font to place in the app, instead of the original font families I'd like to create and import my own custom font type and use it in my app for text displayed on the screen.

Comment: Not sure I see why this question should be tagged, c++, xcode or import.

Comment: The font will be used in an xcode project just thought it might help.